# Is there anyway to set Quota for users in Fortigate?

Tags: firewall, security, fortigate, fortinet

someone told me that there is a solution for setting Quota in New FortiOS (v5.4), but i can't find anything to do that.

i just want to know, is there anyway to set Quota for my local internet users, or not? if there is, then how?

thank you for your time...

Comment: please, if there is or isn't anyway to do this for all websites tel me...

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a quota via the web filter profile. The quota can be configured per category, and the category action need to be set to either `Monitor / Warning / Authenticate`.

The quota can be a traffic or time restriction, and is on a per user basis. For further information please refer to the FortiOS Handbook, the chapter name is:

> Configuring FortiGuard Category Quotas

[image: FortiGuard Quota Rules]

Comment: it works for all websites or just category?

Comment: That depends on what you configure. You can add a new quota rule and add all categories to the rule (like all websites), or you can create a rule for only some specific categories.